# ASP.NET MVC Using different controllers in single view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC and I find troubles in some MVC patterns.
It's pretty clear the paradigm One controller -> One View but in a complex scenario where I have a wizard page where at every step I collect data for different models I can't find a straight and simple solution.

Example:
I have these 3 models: Student, Subject, Subscription

I want to make a jquery wizard page to create a subscription in this way:

1. Ask to select an existent student or create a new one
2. Ask to select an existent subject or create a new one
3. Ask to input some other data (date start, date end, payment etc)

This wizard is in view Subscription/Create and is using a Subscription model with some ViewBag data.

How can i achieve this?

It's better posting everything to a single controller action and call inserts in every models involved? Or is better post data at each step to the right Action?

Comment: You have two options here - use *one* view and show and hide parts of the wizard with JavaScript or use multiple views and multiple controller actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery for this, then in reality all you need is one viewmodel. That single viewmodel will contain the properties for eveything you intend to collect from the user e.g

```
public class SubscriptionCreateViewModel
{
    // Fields from page 1 of the wizard.
    public string Username { get; set;}

    // Fields from page 2 of the wizard.
    public string Foo { get; set;}

    // etc.
}
```

When the user clicks `Create` (or whatever) on the last step of the wizard, the jQuery can make an Ajax POST call to the Subscriptions controller e.g

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url to controller',
    data : { Username : 'UserName', Foo : 'foo' }
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SubscriptionCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    // Do whatever.
}
```

This implies that all the fields are shown in the same view though, by some JavaScript that changes what fields are shown to the user, based on the current wizard step.

If you are using separate views, then I suggest you use three controllers and three viewmodels, one for each controller (`StudentController`, `StundentCreateViewModel`, `SubjectController`, etc)